# Class conforming to protocol as function parameter in Swift Error

Tags: swift

I'm currently in Swift 3.1 and the following code does not compile.

```
protocol HeaderDisplayable {
    func setTitle(_ string: String)
}

class MyView: UILabel, HeaderDisplayable {
    func setTitle(_ string: String) {
        self.text = string
    }
}

func foo<T: UILabel>(view:T) where T: HeaderDisplayable{
    view.setTitle("HEY")
}

foo(MyView())
```

The error message is saying

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading but you are missing the argument label.  You need to do this:

```
foo(view: MyView())
```

or if you want to remove the need for it you could change the method definition to this:

```
func foo<T: UILabel>(_ view:T) where T: HeaderDisplayable{
    view.setTitle("HEY")
}
```

Either version will work fine.

Comment: Ha that was stupid of me! The error message did not help at all